# Pattern in unix awk command?

Tags: regex, unix, awk, unix-timestamp

```
"original_timestamp" : 1497691757895
```

I have text like this, I want to use awk command and update value of original_timestamp to date format, I  am using

```
awk -F, '{x=$1;sub(/:.*/,strftime(":%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",$1),x);$1=x;}1'
```

but not getting desired output

Comment: Why are you using awk for this?

Comment: Is the input file a json file?

Comment: add more context lines and desired output

Answer (score 0):

I figured something like this:

```
echo "original_timestamp : 1497691757895" | awk -v foo=$(date +%m/%d/%Y:%H:%M:%S) '{ sub(/:.*/,foo) }1'
```

Output:

```
original_timestamp 07/03/2017:17:32:23
```

Is this what you where looking for? The format is not the same you requested but I guess you can figure this out. The point is that you can use the -v to declare a variable that holds the content of the date command. And this variable you can use in the sub command.

Comment: Sorry you are right. At first I thought that strftime is php exclusive.